# Is this the right forum for a "grad school related" question

Tags: support

**background:**
There is a masters program that I am very interested in attending (remotely) and they want letters of recommendation. Previously I had asked former professors, and they did most of the structural work in the letter, but when I asked peers, managers, and coworkers in industry they are asking me to provide a draft. It is really hard for me to "toot my own horn" - that is one of my biggest challenges in the annual review process, or in making a resume.

**question:**
Is this the right forum to ask questions on that topic?

In particular I would like to ask something like the following:

What resources are available for guiding an appropriate letter of recommendation that isn't plagiarism, that evokes the words and perspectives of the recommender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is a valid question, there is a very comprehensive question that exact topic here: [What does it mean if a professor asks you to draft his reference letter for you?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29041/73) I strongly suggest that you check that out before posting a similar question.

Comment: What a fantastic link!  Thank you.